# outlook: why does the application close upon minimize

Tags: microsoft-outlook

When I minimize my outlook, the application closes. It even disappears from the Applications tab of Windows Task manager.

Why?

I have to keep opening out look.

I am running Outlook 2007 SP2 on Windows XP Professional version 2002 SP3.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure? Have you tried right-click the Outlook icon in the Notification Area of the
Taskbar and uncheck "Hide When Minimized"? You will probably still see Outlook in the processes tab of task manager.